# CMake error "Expected a command name"

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm doing a shool assignment which involves CMake.

I'm trying to import the CMake project in CLion but I get the following error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35:   Parse error.  Expected a command
>   name, got unquoted argument with text   "add_subdirectoryâ€‹".

The line specified is the following:

```
#​ ​Add​ ​terminal​ ​sub​ ​directory
add_subdirectory​(​terminal)

target_link_libraries(${Screen}​ ​Terminal)
```

The whole CMake file:

```
# Projektets namn
project(Screen)

# Minsta tillåtna cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

# Kompilera med c++ 11 stöd
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Lägg till katalogen med våra bibliotek till INCLUDE path
# (i dessa kataloger kommer kompilatorn att leta efter de
# header filer som inkluderas i koden)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($ENV{TOOLS_INCLUDE})

# Ta med alla källkodsfiler i den aktuella katalogen och
# lägger dem i listan SRC_LIST.
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

# Om Debug mode
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    # Skriv ut meddelandet Debug mode samt sätt kompilator
    # direktivet DEBUG
    message("Debug mode")
    add_definitions(-DDEBUG)
else(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    # Skriv ut meddelandet Release mode.
    message("Release mode")
endif (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")

# Skapa en exekverbar fil med källkodsfilerna i från
# SRC_LIST. Första parametern är namnet på målet (Target)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

#​ ​Add​ ​terminal​ ​sub​ ​directory
add_subdirectory​(​terminal)
target_link_libraries(${{PROJECT_NAME}​ ​Terminal)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide lines preceding your "add_subdirectory()" command. I suspect a missing closing parenthesis in previous command. BTH, your use of "add_subdirectory()" seems valid

Comment: @Antwane Updated the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command you used is:

```
add_subdirectory​(​terminal)
```

but the `(` char is preceded and followed by a null char. This is invisible, but can be debugged using a hex editor, or any text editor that highlight this kind of error (I detected it using Sublime Text).

Simply replace this line by:

```
add_subdirectory(terminal)
```

Note: see the difference between 2 lines in HxD, a hexadecimal editor:

[image]

Comment: mmm I have the same problem but with an hexadecimal editor I see nothing of this sort

Comment: This must've been a particular case